# Cast to self pointer in static method throws segfault on (derived) method call

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to implement a simple thread starter class. Below you find a *Simple base class* implementation and 2 derived variations that are supposed to work as starters. The first one throws segfaults at `static void* Threaded::run (void* self)` sporadically. I suppose this might a pointer issue but I am not able to figure out why?

Does `this` in `Threaded::start` point to a wrong address or is there any other issue with my first derivation?

This is how it's used:

```
Thread thread (ptr_to_some_obj);
thread.start (&this_obj::callback);
thread.detach ();
```

**Simple base class**

```
class Threaded
{

public:

    Threaded () {/* empty */}
    virtual ~Threaded () {/* empty */}

    /** Returns true if the thread was successfully started, false if there was an error starting the thread */
    bool start ()
    {
        return (pthread_create (&_thread, NULL, run, this) == 0);
    }

    /** Implement this method in your subclass with the code which allows to gently stop execution. */
    virtual void stop () = 0;

    /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
    void wait ()
    {
        (void) pthread_join (_thread, NULL);
    }

    bool detach ()
    {
        return (pthread_detach (_thread) == 0);
    }

protected:

   /** Implement this method in your subclass with the code you want your thread to run. */
   virtual void run () = 0;

   static void* run (void* self)
   {
       ((Threaded*) self) -> run ();
       return NULL;
   }

   pthread_t _thread;
};
```

**Derived class 1** (throws segfault at `((Threaded*) self) -> run ();` above)

```
typedef void (*staticcall)(void*);

class Thread : public Threaded
{
public:

    Thread (void* passthru)
        :_call (NULL)
    {
        _passthru = passthru;
    }

    ~Thread () { /* empty */ }

    bool start (staticcall call)
    {
        _call = call;
        assert (_call);
        return start ();
    }

    void stop ()
    {
        // nothing
    }

protected:

    void run ()
    {
        (_call) (_passthru);
    }

    bool start ()
    {
        return Threaded::start ();
    }

private:

    Thread () { };
    void* _passthru;
    staticcall _call;
};
```

**Derived class 2** (works, but i'd rather have *Derived class 1* implementation)

```
typedef void (*staticcall)(void*);

class Thread2 : public Threaded
{
public:

    Thread2 (void* passthru)
    {
        _passthru = passthru;
    }

    ~Thread2 () { /* empty */ }

    bool start (staticcall call)
    {
        _call = call;
        assert (_call);
        return start ();
    }

    void stop ()
    {
        // nothing
    }

protected:

    void run () { }

    static void* run2 (void*)
    {
        (_call) (_passthru);
        return NULL;
    }

    bool start ()
    {
        return (pthread_create (&_thread, NULL, run2, NULL) == 0);
    }

private:

    Thread2 () { };
    static void* _passthru;
    static staticcall _call;
};

void* Thread2::_passthru;
staticcall Thread2::_call;
```

Comment: Prime suspect is `thread` having been destroyed at the point of the call, causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: That was my first guess, but I couldn't verify it. I also don't see how `thread` is destroyed during the call of `thread.start`. It's not like something is running async until the seg fault.

Comment: `pthread_create` only queues the new thread. There are no guarantees regarding when the thread function will be called, and `thread` must be alive at that time.

Comment: ouw.. okay that puts it in another light. But then again, would the 2nd approaching not be failing at `Thread2::run2` sporadically? Aye.. not failing but they could lead to undefined behaviour if new Thread2 objects are created too fast, right?

Comment: "Undefined behaviour" only means that anything can happen. In this particular case, the lack of a virtual call makes it not crash. It's still undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by molbdnilo:

> `pthread_create` only queues the new thread. There are no guarantees regarding when the thread function will be called, and `thread` must be alive at that time.

Since I do not want to keep a list of spawned threads around I solved this with the use of `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`. The spawner will wait for a signal that is emitted by the method that runs in the thread. This way the thread creator won't destroy the thread object before the to-be-threaded method is called.

```
class ThreadSpawner
{
public:

    ThreadSpawner ()
    {
        pthread_mutex_init (&MtxThreadStarter, 0);
        pthread_cond_init (&CondThreadStarter, 0);
    }

    ~ThreadSpawner ()
    {
        pthread_cond_destroy (&CondThreadStarter);
        pthread_mutex_destroy (&MtxThreadStarter);
    }

    void spawn ()
    {
        Thread thread (pass_object);
        pthread_mutex_lock (&MtxThreadStarter);
        if (thread.start (&ThreadSpawner::callback))
        {
            // wait here for signal
            pthread_cond_wait (&CondThreadStarter, &MtxThreadStarter);
            thread.detach ();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&MtxThreadStarter);
    }

    static void callback (void* passthru)
    {
        // send signal to thread spawner
        pthread_mutex_lock (&MtxThreadStarter);
        pthread_cond_signal (&CondThreadStarter);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&MtxThreadStarter);

        // do threaded work
    }

private:

    static pthread_mutex_t MtxThreadStarter;
    static pthread_cond_t CondThreadStarter;    
}

pthread_mutex_t ThreadSpawner::MtxThreadStarter = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t ThreadSpawner::CondThreadStarter = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

Comment: Well that seems a bit of an overkill to me. If you intend to call `wait()`, you don't need all this fuss since your `Thread` instance will be alive for the whole thread duration. Synchronization is only needed when you call `detach()` immediately after launching your thread and the `Thread` instance goes out of scope before the stub in `Threaded` has been called. I would rather block the `Threaded` destructor until the thread starts running. That could solve the problem transparently with only a mutex and practically no overhead.

Comment: Actually you could even throw an exception in your destructor if you see that `detach()` or `wait()` have never been called, to avoid a scenario where the user calls `start()` and lets the `Thread` instance go out of scope without doing anything.

Comment: That sounds like a smart approach. In my case I am not indending to call `wait()`. Could you give a code example for blocking the destructor with a mutex? If I am right the mutex unlock would be inside `Thread:run`, before or after the callback call? If it's unlocked before then the callback is probably not called and if it's unlocked after the `Thread` object will stay until the actual job is finished - is the latter your intention?

Comment: `pthread_create` will just add `Threaded::run()` address to the list of ready tasks for later calling by the scheduler. The critical point is when `Threaded::run()` is done using `Threaded` attributes, namely "real" thread entry point and prm. So the mutex release can occur once `Threaded::run()` has used these last, i.e. just before calling the "real" entry point. As for the destructor, it just has to wait on the mutex before doing its job. The wait will last at most for the time between `Thread::start()` and first thread activation by the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit: a solution to let a thread execute as a method invokation**

Well the solution I thought about in the recent discussion would work *if* the thread entry point was a simple function.
However, I suppose the idea is more to take advantage of an actual object, so that the thread body is actually an invokation of the `body()` method.

This is more tricky, since there must be a live instance of the derived class for the whole thread duration, and yet the original instance is likely to get out of scope after a `start` / `detach` sequence.

One possible (though somewhat costly) solution is to have the thread body stub create a local copy of the original instance on the stack. So the thread launcher will construct a thread object, and the thread itself will copy it.

With this system, you only need to make sure the original instance will be kept live in the interval between `pthread_create` and thread activation by the scheduler.

This requires a semaphore (which will be done by hand with a mutex/cond. var. pair for the 1.000.000th time, since bloody C++11 does not have one in store).

To hide this messy code inside the base class, you need to downcast the base pointer into the appropriate subclass type.
I resorted to templating the base class, though there might be smarter solutions out there. I just could not think of any.

To test the solution, I use a counter system that detects whether the original Thread instance has been deleted before the thread stub could make a local copy.

The SYNC compilation flag activates the semaphore. The expected program output is `0->0`. If other numbers appear, it means some threads ran on messed-up instances.

I tested it on Ubuntu in a VM, and it seemed to work well enough.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <thread> // sleep_for
#include <chrono> // milliseconds
#include <pthread.h>

#define SYNC // undefine this to see what happens without synchronization

typedef void *(*tEntryPoint) (void *);


#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class semaphore {
private:
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable v;
    int c;

public:
    semaphore (int count = 0):c(count){}

    void V()
    {
#ifdef SYNC
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        c++;
        v.notify_one();
#endif
    }
    void P()
    {
#ifdef SYNC
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        while (c == 0) v.wait(l);
        c--;
#endif
    }
};

template<typename Derived>
class Threaded
{
public:

    /** Returns true if the thread was successfully started, false if there was an error starting the thread */
    bool start(void)
    {
        destructor_guard = new semaphore();
        bool res = (pthread_create(&_thread, NULL, (tEntryPoint)entry_point, this) == 0);
        if (res) destructor_guard->P();      // wait fot thread to start execution
        delete destructor_guard;
        return res;
    }

    /** This optional method will be executed after the thread main body */
    virtual void stop() {}

    /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
    void wait()
    {
        (void)pthread_join(_thread, NULL);
    }

    /** Will let the underlying task run independently */
    bool detach()
    {
        return (pthread_detach(_thread) == 0);
    }

private:
    static void * entry_point(Derived * self)
    {
        Derived local_self = *self;
        local_self.destructor_guard->V(); // original can be deleted
        local_self.body();
        local_self.stop();
        return NULL;
    }

    pthread_t _thread;
    semaphore* destructor_guard;
};

#define NUM_THREADS 9
#define REPEAT 3000
static int signature[NUM_THREADS + 1] = { 0, };

class Thread : public Threaded<Thread>
{
    unsigned id;
public:
    Thread(unsigned id) : id(id) {}
    ~Thread() { id = 0; }

    void body(void)
    {
        signature[id%(NUM_THREADS+1)]++;
    }

    void stop(void)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        signature[id%(NUM_THREADS+1)]++;
    }
};

void launch_a_thread(int id)
{
    Thread thread (id);
    if (thread.start())
    {
//        thread.wait();
        thread.detach();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i != REPEAT*NUM_THREADS; i++) launch_a_thread(1+i%NUM_THREADS);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); // leave enough time for free running threads to terminate
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= NUM_THREADS ; i++) if (signature[i] != 2*REPEAT) printf ("%d -> %d\n", i, signature[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that I have to keep the Thread object existent the way I am using it after the thread is started. **Object A** creates a thread **Object B**. Inside **Object B** I am calling a static method of **Object A** as a parallel thread. **Object A** is always existent and the way that I see it is that **Object B** can be destroyed after the thread was started. That's not causing any trouble so far.

Comment: Depends on where the address and parameter of your function are stored. Here you store both in your subclass, and nothing guarantees the thread will start executing your `run()` method immediately after `pthread_create()`. It might be called at the next scheduler tick, which leaves ample time for the object to be destroyed. Of course this will not happen very often, but for a given code pattern causing some implicit synchronization it's a possibility. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're right. As long as the to-be-threaded method is not running, because execution is delayed, the thread object needs to be existent. I solved the issue by using thread conditions, so now Object A will wait until the method called by Object B has signaled that it's running before the Thread object is deleted from the stack. I'll post my solution in a bit.